# unexpected $end in foreach loop

Tags: php

I am getting  error which cause unexpected $end.Without loop its works but not working with foreach loop.Any help is appreciated.I am getting error of unexpected $end.My code is here.How could i solve this?`enter code here`

```
<?php 
              global $mysqli;
              $res_rdid2 = $objfetch->fetch_relation("route_id,did_id","where `did_id`=$id and `timeset_id`='0' and `routing_type`='ER'");
              error_log("----fetch ----$res_rdid2--");
              $ext_type="";
              $encrypt_id = "";
              $t= $res_rdid2[0]['route_id'];
              error_log("====$t==");
              echo $res_rdid2['route_id'];
              $result = $objfetch->fetch_didCallRouting("*","where `route_id`='".$res_routeid2['route_id']."' and `did_id`='".$res_routeid2['did_id']."' ORDER BY priority ASC ");
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {
                        $encrypt_id = base64_encode($row['id']);
                        if($row['ext_type']=="a"){$ext_type="Actual";}
                        if($row['ext_type']=="v"){$ext_type="Virtual";}
                        if($row['ext_type']=="vm"){$ext_type="Voice Mail";}

                        //fetch DID
                        $result2 = $objfetch->fetch_did("`DID`,`did_name`","where `id`='".$row['did_id']."'");
                        $didname2 = "";
                        if($result2[0]['did_name']!="")
                        {
                            $didname2 = " (".$result2[0]['did_name'].")";
                        }

                        //fetch extension
                        if($row['ext_type']=="a" or $row['ext_type']=="vm")
                        {
                            $result3 = $objfetch->fetch_ext("`ext_number`", "where `id`='".$row['ext_id']."'");
                            $ext = $result3[0]['ext_number'];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $result4 = $objfetch->fetch_virtualext("`ext`", "where `id`='".$row['ext_id']."'");
                            $ext = $result4[0]['ext'];
                        }

        ?>              
                      <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $result2[0]['did'].$didname2;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo "To Extension";?></td>
                        <td><?php echo "-";?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['priority'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $ext_type;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $ext;?></td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php}?>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr>
                    <td><?php echo $result2[0]['did'].$didname2;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "To Extension";?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "-";?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['priority'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $ext_type;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $ext;?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php  }  ?>  // please give space here.
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the PHP closing tag `?>` before `<tr>`.

Try this.

I have also improved the readability of the code.

```php
<?php 

    global $mysqli;

    $res_rdid2 = $objfetch->fetch_relation(
        "route_id, did_id",
        "where `did_id`= {$id} and `timeset_id`='0' and `routing_type`='ER'"
    );

    error_log("----fetch ----{$res_rdid2}--");

    $ext_type   = "";
    $encrypt_id = "";
    $t = $res_rdid2[0]['route_id'];

    error_log("===={$t}==");

    echo $res_rdid2['route_id'];

    $result = $objfetch->fetch_didCallRouting(
        "*",
        "where `route_id` = '{$res_routeid2['route_id']}' and `did_id` = '{$res_routeid2['did_id']}' ORDER BY priority ASC"
    );

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $encrypt_id = base64_encode($row['id']);

        if($row['ext_type'] === "a")
            $ext_type = "Actual";

        if($row['ext_type'] === "v")
            $ext_type = "Virtual";

        if($row['ext_type'] === "vm")
            $ext_type = "Voice Mail";

        // Fetch DID.

        $result2  = $objfetch->fetch_did(
            "`DID`, `did_name`",
            "where `id` = '{$row['did_id']}'"
        );

        $didname2 = "";

        if($result2[0]['did_name'] != "")
            $didname2 = " ({$result2[0]['did_name']})";

        // Fetch extension.

        if($row['ext_type'] === "a" or $row['ext_type'] === "vm")
        {
            $result3 = $objfetch->fetch_ext(
                "`ext_number`", 
                "where `id`='{$row['ext_id']}'"
            );

            $ext = $result3[0]['ext_number'];
        }
        else
        {
            $result4 = $objfetch->fetch_virtualext(
                "`ext`",
                "where `id`='{$row['ext_id']}'"
            );

            $ext = $result4[0]['ext'];
        }

        ?>        

        <tr>
            <td><?= $result2[0]['did'].$didname2 ?></td>
            <td>"To Extension"</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><?= $row['priority'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $ext_type ?></td>
            <td><?= $ext ?></td>
        </tr>


    <?php

    }

    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No `}` is missing. It is closed after printing the `tr`. And OP needs to print the `tr` inside the loop.

Comment: @b0s3 Fixed. The code was not very readable.

Comment: Now it is changing the output as `tr`s should be printed inside the loop.

Comment: no success.I have update my code please check

Comment: You can try now. @b0se question fixed

Comment: You could improve the readability **further** by using the [alternative control structure syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: @GiamPy The `foreach()` closing brace. I'll admit, however, that I only saw that and didn't see that the top-half of the code was all just PHP.

Comment: error solved.But didn't get any value table.

Comment: @soni8010 It's likely to be another issue in the code unrelated to this question.

Comment: i got value before without foreach

Answer (score 0):

put

```
?>
```

after

```
if($row['ext_type']=="a" or $row['ext_type']=="vm")
{
  $result3 = $objfetch->fetch_ext("`ext_number`", "where `id`='".$row['ext_id']."'");
  $ext = $result3[0]['ext_number'];
}
else
{
  $result4 = $objfetch->fetch_virtualext("`ext`", "where `id`='".$row['ext_id']."'");
  $ext = $result4[0]['ext'];
}
```